# Convert Python generated protobuf to java without .proto file

Tags: java, python, reverse-engineering, protocol-buffers

Today I receive some Python files (.py) generated from Protocol Buffer (v2). Is there anyway i can convert them to Java version without the original .proto file ? I know it sounds silly but it's just that i'm working on a project for a new client and this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jythonc](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/jythonc.html) tool supplied with Jython.